# Error while running CMake outside Android studio

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am a beginner in android and working on an android native project. I am trying to use `Cmake` outside android studio using command line. As per Android docs , I run following command as per `build_command.txt`:

```
    /Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/cmake -H/Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/cpp \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON  \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21 \
-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 \
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja \
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1a412025/obj/arm64-v8a \
-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1a412025/obj/arm64-v8a \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
-B/Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/.cxx/Debug/1a412025/arm64-v8a \
-GNinja \
-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang \
-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared \
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21
```

but I am getting following error:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/cpp
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21
zsh: command not found: -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a
```

It is generating ninja files but not building C++ libs. Can I build C++ libs with CMake via one command like ndk-build script.

Comment: "I run following command as per `build_command.txt`" - This file contains **several commands**, each command on its own line. You can easily find that out from the errors you got: `zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android` tells that `zsh` tries to run the second line. If you want to run all these lines as a single command, add ``\`` at the end of every line except of the last one. That way shell will be aware that all lines should be combined before running the command.

Comment: Now I am getting CMake Error: The source directory "/Users/vmangal/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/cpp/ " does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
zsh: command not found: -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21
zsh: no such file or directory: -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/vmangal/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529


even though Cmakelists.txt exist at specified path

Comment: As zsh errors are not gone, it seems you haven't properly finalize all lines. See e.g. [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477166/507465) about how to do that correctly. If it won't help, update your question post with new content of your command.